# jOOQ how to execute Postgresql functions and operators

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm using jooq 3.9.1. I would like to write queries by adding conditions based on PostgreSQL operators and functions.

E.g., for arrays there are a lot of operators, like `&&` or functions like `array_prepend` that I would like to use.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I believe there should be something like

```java
int[] array_of_values = {1,2,3};

selectOne()
  .from(TABLE)
  .where(TABLE.COL_A.eq("Hello"))
  .and(TABLE.COL_B.operator("&&").of(array_of_values))
  .fetch();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jOOQ 3.9, the standard way to go forward here is to [use the plain SQL API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/)

```java
selectOne()
  .from(TABLE)
  .where(TABLE.COL_A.eq("Hello"))
  .and("{0} && {1}", TABLE.COL_B, val(array_of_values))
  .fetch();
```

This is using the [`SelectConditionStep.and(String, QueryPart...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectConditionStep.html#and-java.lang.String-org.jooq.QueryPart...-) method for convenience, but there are other ways, including using [`DSL.condition()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#condition-java.lang.String-org.jooq.QueryPart...-)

Your idea is a very good one. I've registered a [feature request for jOOQ 3.10](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5815).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
It would be also nice to have per each dialect an enum with the operators to be called, so that we could avoid to pass a `String` to the operator method, but I understand that it could be too much extrawork.

Comment: @mat_boy: Don't worry, there will (eventually) be an `org.jooq.Operator` type to abstract over this. Not sure about the enum, because users can define their own operators in most databases, so there will be operator code generation, e.g. for Oracle: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3710

Answer (score 0):

There currently is a `arrayOverlap()` function for the operator in Postgres.
https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/util/postgres/PostgresDSL.html#arrayOverlap(org.jooq.Field,org.jooq.Field)